# Get previous url from chrome.tabs.onUpdated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The chrome.tabs API provides us a way to listen to the change in the url for each tab. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated

I can add a listener like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    // changeInfo.url gives the updated url if it's changed
    // tab.url gives the current url for the tab
});
```

What I'd like to do is to detect if the domain changes and perform some actions if it does.

For example if the url changes from https://google.com/abc to https://google.com do something.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is no good way to get the previous url from the chrome.tabs API.
What I'm currently doing is to have a hashmap that keeps track of the previous url for each tabId like this:

```
var tabIdToPreviousUrl = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (changeInfo.url && changeInfo.url.match(/<regex>/g)) {
        var previousUrl = "";
        if (tabId in tab) {
            previousUrl = tabIdToPreviousUrl[tabId];
        }
        // If the domain is different perform action.
        if (previousUrl !== changeInfo.url) {
            // do something
        }
        // Add the current url as previous url
        tabIdToPreviousUrl[tabId] = changeInfo.url;
    }
});
```

Comment: What if a tab is closed? I guess you can use `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var previousUrl = "";

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  //Your code here
});

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(object){ 
 chrome.tabs.get(object.tabId, function(tab){ previousUrl = tab.url;});
});
```

*Note that you will need "webNavigation" listed in your manifest.json*

Comment: `onBeforeNavigate` even only happens when the page reloads. It omits browser's back and forward and client and/or server redirect and `history.pushState()`. So this answer is not correct.